# Button reload own partial view Asp .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My problem is that I only want to reload (on button click) this Partial View in which the button is in.

It looks like:

**View:**

```
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.Height; x++)
{
<tr>
    @for (int y = 0; y < Model.Witdh; y++)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", new Test() { X = x, Y = y, Type = Models.OwnType.Unknown)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

**PartialView (MyPartialView)**

```
@model Client.Models.Test

@if (Model.Type == Models.OwnType.Unknow)
{
    <div id="Unknow">
            <input id="fire" type=submit value="fire" />
    </div>
}
else if (Model.Type == Models.OwnType.Type.A)
{
    <div id="TypeA">A</div>
}
else if (Model.Type == Models.OwnType.Type.B)
{
    <div id="TypeB">B</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ChangeAt(int x,int y)
{
    var model = // change type

    return PartialView("MyPartialView", model);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Test
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public OwnType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

razor is not going to be able to help you here.  The full page razor view is created before any of it is sent down to the browser.  You could use an iframe to get the behavior you want and instead of making it a partial view just make it a full view in the iframe.  Otherwise, it's likely javascript/jquery type solution which is what most people do.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. But the most jquery solutions reload a partial view with a button outside the partial view. Is it also possible with a script when the button is inside because I think I need a dynamic selector?

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this but it sounds like you are generating a huge html output.  You could but some JavaScript in the partial view that would save the right values with closure.  My gut tells me this is more an Angularjs problem.  Sorry for not helping more.